# Is it possible to have an rspec double with a default response?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I want to mock an object that might receive any number of messages that I don't care about.  I'd like this object to have a default answer, such as 'true', with the ability to add specific methods and answers where it does matter.  Is it possible to do this in RSpec?  What I'd like is something like this:

```
obj = default_double(default: true, widget_count: 5)
obj.foobar.should == true
obj.widget_count.should == 5
```

It'd be nice if I could pass in a lambda or proc as a return value and have the default_double return the evaluation of that lambda.  It would be extra-nice if the proc or lambda was evaluated in the context of the test, with access to the variables available in the example.

So if the features above were added, we might have something like:

```
@widgets = WidgetContainer.new
@widgets.widget_count = 5
obj = default_double(default: true, widget_count: lambda { @widgets.widget_count })
obj.foobar.should == true
obj.widget_count.should == 5
```

If a motivation for this feature is interesting to the reader, let's assume either that I don't want to dig and find out all the possible messages it could receive, or the set of possible messages is extremely large or unknown.

Is anything like this built in to RSpec?

Comment: Why do you want this feature? I don't see the use case for it at all.

Comment: I have an object in a complex object hierarchy that needs to exist and needs to respond to a variety of messages, but I really don't care anything about it.  It's a sort of logger object.  The return value is not terribly important, but responding to the methods called is.  My choices are grovel through the entire enormous app and figure out what calls are made to this object and stub them, many perhaps unnecessarily for my test, or just have a default answer, with specific return values for those methods where it is required.

Comment: Having said that, I'd like to keep comments/answers focused on the facts.  Either RSpec can or can not provide a default value for a mock.  If you happen to know that it can't, then "no, it can't" is a fine answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'll take a shot at answering the question:

I believe that RSpec does *not* have a built-in mock capability which will receive an arbitrary message and return a default value. However, it does allow you to specify a return value as a block which, along with Ruby's `method_missing` feature, should allow you to fairly readily construct the `default_double` method you describe above.

Here's a cut at it that passes the above example, although it could benefit from some refactoring:

```
require 'spec_helper'

def default_double(args)
  object = Object.new
  args.each do |key, value|
    if key == :default
      object.define_singleton_method(:method_missing) { |method, *args, &block| value }
    elsif Proc === value
      expect(object).to receive(key) do value.call end
    else expect(object).to receive(key).and_return(value)
    end
  end
  object
end

class WidgetContainer
  attr_accessor :widget_count
end

describe "default_double test" do
  it "should pass" do
    @widgets = WidgetContainer.new
    @widgets.widget_count = 5
    obj = default_double(default: true, widget_count: lambda { @widgets.widget_count })
    obj.foobar.should == true
    obj.widget_count.should == 5
  end
end
```

Comment: Right....that's the kind of thing I was thinking I'd have to do, but it is elegant and nice.  I like your implementation.  I had been manually creating classes with a method_missing and returning the default value.  This is much better.  Thanks!